# How do I get length of my Json Object

Tags: javascript, json

Below is my JSON object

```
{"Decision":[{"recid":"1183","reason":"Approved as Requested","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"662","reason":"3","decision":"Rejected","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"752","reason":"Approved People Resources; But No Funding Approved","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""}]}
```

How do I get length of this.In this example it should return me 3.
My Object name is DecisionObj which have above listed elements.

Comment: Decision.length would give it but please google before posting such questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var string = '{"Decision":[{"recid":"1183","reason":"Approved as Requested","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"662","reason":"3","decision":"Rejected","approvalamt":"","comment":""},{"recid":"752","reason":"Approved People Resources; But No Funding Approved","decision":"Approved","approvalamt":"","comment":""}]}';

var object = JSON.parse(string);

alert(object.Decision.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have `length` property. You can use that.

```
var length =  DecisionObj.length;
```